# Shade area between two vertical lines in a time series in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I need to know how to shade an area in a time series plot. I need to shade this [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iupd5.jpg) from 2010 to 2015, this is the code I´m using as example, Thank guys:

```
x=rnorm(240)
x
w = ts(x, freq = 12, start = c(1996,1))
w
ts.plot(w)
```

Comment: Please tag the software you're using to render the plot

Comment: in ts.plot(w), the range between 2010 to 2015, two vertical lines and gray or other color in that range.